# MySQL Function, must bring back a row

Tags: mysql, null

I have this simple MySQL statement:

```
 SELECT 
   ((AVG(q1) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q15)) / 3 ) AS Res  
 FROM tresults 
 WHERE id = '1' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1'
 GROUP BY q25
```

Now, if there are no rows with the date **MARCH2010** then the query returns zero results (which is correct) but I'd like it to return a row - even if the result is **NULL**.

Comment: Why do you want it to return a row if it correctly returns none and what should that row contain?

Comment: Bring back NULL will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select a single row as a constant, and then `left join` it to your result set:

```
select l.*, r.* 
from (select "your constant" as constant) as l 
left join ( 
  SELECT 
     ((AVG(q1) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q15)) / 3 ) AS Res  
   FROM tresults 
   WHERE id = '1' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1'
   GROUP BY q25
) as r on 1
```

How this works:

- `select "your constant" as constant` always returns a single row
- `left join` always returns all of the rows in the `left` table at least once
- if the `right` table has no rows, then the entire `left` table is extended with a bunch of null columns, and the result has one row
- if the `right` table has n rows, the result has n rows that each have an additional "your constant" column

Comment: Looks interesting - however, I get the following error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Homer_J -- I forgot an alias after the join table; I've updated my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely positive, but this case statement might work.  I can't test it atm.

```
Case When 
  (SELECT 
   Count(*)  
   FROM tresults 
   WHERE id = '1' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1'
   GROUP BY q25) > 0
Then
  SELECT 
   ((AVG(q1) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q15)) / 3 ) AS Res  
   FROM tresults 
   WHERE id = '1' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1'
   GROUP BY q25
Else
  SELECT null
End
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
   ((AVG(q1) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q15)) / 3 ) AS Res
 FROM tresults 
 WHERE id = '1' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1'
 GROUP BY q25

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS Res
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
   ((AVG(q1) + AVG(q8) + AVG(q15)) / 3 ) AS Res
 FROM tresults 
 WHERE id = '1' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1'
 GROUP BY q25
)

Will always return one row beacuse of second part.